# SCCM PXE Boot configuration for specific MAC addresses

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm

On SCCM Distribution point properties, PXE tab I'm configuring it to respond to PXE requests only from specified MAC addresses ("Respond to PXE requests on specific network interfaces"). When adding a new MAC address, it says that for the settings to take effect, it requires a service restart - "Binding to an address requires a service restart.".
I can't figure out which service exactly needs to be restarted. Do you guys have any idea? I'm running SCCM version 1810. Been digging through Microsoft documentation, but didn't find a thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would first try the wds. It's called "Windows Deployment Services Server" or "WDSServer" and is probably installed on your distribution point. I don't think it can be restarted from within the console you have to connect there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked "Enable a PXE responder without Windows Deployment Service" in the distribution point settings?

If not, this should be the "Windows Deployment Services Server" service on the distribution point server.

If you enabled this option. I think the correct service is the "ConfigMgr PXE Responder service".